# Ember get inconsistent behavior

Tags: ember.js

I find an inconsistent behavior of Ember.get on refreshing events (Ember.run loop for observers/computed properties).
I have a child controller that tries getting model of its parent controller:

```
App.ParentRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
   queryParams:{
      someProperty: {
          refreshModel: false,
          replace: true
      }
      model: function(params){
          return this.store.find('parent-model', params.id, {reload:true}
........
});

App.ParentChildController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   parent: Ember.inject.controller(),
   someProperty: Ember.computed.alias('parent.someProperty'),
   anObserver: function(){
      var someRelation = this.get('parent.model.someRelation'); // problem line
   }.observes('someProperty').on('init') 
});

App.ParentModel = DS.Model.extend({
   someRelation: hasMany('relation', { async: false });
   ....
});
```

It works on the controller initialisation. But on the parent refresh it raises an error:

TypeError: this.get(...) is undefined

someRelation is an async=false relation which is side loaded. So if I put a breakpoint on the problem line the following works:

```
this.get('parent.model').get('someRelation');
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `someRelation` variable inside the observer?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `someRelation` as well as what your model looks like?

Comment: well someProperty is a queryParam for the parent route which refreshes the parent's model on changes. I will update the question with the additional information

Comment: @alexlafroscia, I think it does not essentially matter what is going on with someRelation variable inside the observer as the observer cannot get it.

Comment: @DimD it _does_ matter because of the timing of when observers are executed.  The short story is that you should avoid using an observer, since you can always find a better way to do it.  The long story is that the parent controller might not have the model defined at the point that the child controller is being initialized, and the observer will eagerly re-compute the property.  Is there a reason you can't use a computed property? They are much more reliable.

Comment: @alexlafroscia, yes I agree with you that there can be a more appropriate, from Ember's point of view, way of doing it. In my case the use of observer is more easy because the 'someProperty' is a user selection in the parent controller and on its change, I recalculate lots of properties on the child controller in the observer. Using computed properties would make me create plenty of that instead of one observer. But essentially this is not THE question. The question is why this.get('parent.model').get('someRelation') and this.get('parent.model.someRelation') does not return the same?

Comment: I think your problem is using `init` in the observer function.. I believe a controller can be initialised and not actually have a model assigned because the route hasn't assigned it yet.. This could explain why it works with a breakpoint also? The breakpoint just delays the execution and by the time you press 'next' or 'step over' or whatever it is the controller has been populated correctly

Comment: @DimD I'm pretty sure that the use of the observer vs. a computed property really is the right question to ask.  Without working code to confirm this, my guess is that the observer being called on initialization is trying to get the property of the parent before it exists.  If you provide a JSBin of the broken functionality, I would be happy to try to create one in which it works.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, it makes sense that the init is the problem.